# TypeScript - either access generic type information for interfaces or generate code to provide it?

Tags: typescript

Does typescript have a mechanism to allow me to interrogate `T` in `f<T>()` below for its type name/properties? `f()` does not need an instance of T to do its work, only info about T's type name and shape.

Given something like:

```
interface Foo {
    bar:string
}

function f<T>() {
    // know about T here?
}

var x = f<Foo>()
```

Assuming not, is there a supported way (macros, preprocessor, compiler plugin, etc?) in TS to *generate code* to make that visible?

For background, what I'd like to build is a generic data access layer that pulls data from a SQL database where the table name and columns to retrieve correspond to the type name and properties respectively.

For example `get<User>(userid:number)` could roughly create a query like `SELECT name FROM User WHERE id = userid` provided `User` defines a `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider...

1. The typing TypeScript uses is only available at development time, not runtime
2. There are constructs in place to know more about the generic type your function is using

Example

```
interface IBaseDataStructure {
  id: number;
  createDate: Date;
  [string]: any;
}

function insert<T extends IBaseDataStructure> (dataToSave: T) {
  // knows that dataToSave has id & createDate
  dataToSave.id = 1;
  dataToSave.createDate = new Date();
  buildSQL(dataToSave);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brocco. I ask about code generation in my question because of your point #1.  For #2, unfortunately a base class only provides part of the structure and I'm looking to retrieve  the data not save it (there is no argument `dataToSave`).

Comment: For #1 you can look into annotations/decorators. For #2, you can still use `T` internally even if there are no params... `function foo <T extends IX> () { var bar: T; }`